# Conformal mappings of multiply-connected regions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, conformal-geometry

I'm reading about conformal mappings in Ahlfors' text, and I got to this section:

> In the following $\Omega$ denotes a plane region of connectivity $n > 1$. The components of the complement are denoted by $E_1, E_2, \dots, E_n$,  and we take $E_n$ to be the unbounded component. *Without loss of generality we can and will assume that no $E_k$ reduces to a point*, for it is clear that a point component is a removable singularity of any mapping function, and consequently the mappings remain the same if this isolated boundary point is added to the region.

I think this statement is false. For example, consider the region $\Omega=\{0<|z|<1 \} $ which has connectivity 2, with components $E_1=\{0\}$ and $E_2=\{|z| \geq 1\} \cup \{ \infty \}$.

The function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ maps $\Omega$ conformally onto its exterior $\{|z|>1\}$, and although $E_1$ reduces to point, the singularity of $f$ there is of a pole type (which is **not** removable).

Am I right here? If so, what do you think the author meant to say?

Thanks!

Comment: View the mappings as holomorphic mappings to the sphere. A pole is a removable singularity then.

Comment: @DanielFischer But introduing $\infty$, what happens to the notions of holomorphicity and conformality?

Comment: Not much. If you know the notion of a manifold, the sphere is one, and maps to/from the sphere are holomorphic/conformal when they are such as expressed in the coordinate charts. We have the two charts $\operatorname{id} \colon \widehat{\mathbb{C}}\setminus \{\infty\} \to \mathbb{C};\; z \mapsto z$, and $\psi \colon \widehat{\mathbb{C}}\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{C}; z \mapsto \frac1z\;(\infty \mapsto 0)$. So $f$ is holomorphic/conformal in $\infty$ iff $f\circ \psi$ is holomorphic/conformal in $0$ (supposing $f(\infty)\neq \infty$), $\psi\circ f\circ\psi$ if $f(\infty)=\infty$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you. Correct me if I'm wrong, but Ahlfors never discussed this(?). In that case I'll take it as a definition.

Comment: Looks indeed like Ahlfors never discusses that. But without it, you must have special restrictions on the domains resp. mapping functions that would make the entire theory cumbersome.

Comment: @DanielFischer If you will make your comment into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Ahlfors wrote that with mappings between regions of the Riemann sphere in mind.

If you consider only plane regions, as you noticed, an isolated singularity can be a pole, and thus is not a removable singularity of a holomorphic function $f \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$. When considering regions in the sphere, the mappings are viewed as holomorphic mappings $\Omega \to \widehat{\mathbb{C}}$, and then an isolated singularity of a conformal map is necessarily removable - viewed as a holomorphic function, if the isolated singularity is not removable in that sense, it must be a simple pole (by injectivity; a holomorphic function cannot be injective in a punctured neighbourhood of an essential singularity or multiple pole), and extending $f$ by $f(z_0) = \infty$ into the isolated singularity then produces a conformal mapping between regions in the sphere.